# Override the default phone dialer app with a Cordova app when clicking in a phone number

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to make my Cordova app open phone numbers on it and treat the selected number on the app.

When we click on a phone number in some apps, the number is opened on the default phone dialer of the phone. I thought that my app could show in the dialer apps list and the user could select it instead of the default one.

I searched on the on Google and Cordova documentation but didn't found anything.

The option would show in a scenário like the one bellow, when we search for a store or a restaurant and it does have a phone number or when someone send you a phone number on Whatsapp:
[image]

After clicking it, the device opens the phone dial app (the image shows what happens when we click it on a desktop device)
[image]

Instead of opening the defaul dial app, it would show an option to select my  Cordova app, something like this but for the dial app:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add call-number
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/call-number@4
```

on phone number click add below function:

```
 import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';
    
    constructor(private callNumber: CallNumber) { }
    
    this.callNumber.callNumber("18001010101", true)
      .then(res => console.log('Launched dialer!', res))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error launching dialer', err));
```

If you want to open chooser dialog pass second parameter to false to show chooser to choose app for calling.

Comment: The [`call-number`](https://github.com/rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin) plugin seems to be archived...